# Google Sheets Custom Menu to Hide Row based on text value in column 1

Tags: google-sheets, menu, row, hide

I am new to Google Sheets and I am struggling with the following:

1. add custom menu to "TestSheet" namend "Hide" with menu items "Hide Rows" and "Unhide Rows"
2. when the "Hide Row" menu item is clicked, all rows from Row 3 downward in this "TestSheet" should be hidden if the "text value" in Column A is equal to "Value1" or "Value2", if there is "Value3" nothing should happen.
3. when "Unhide Rows" is clicked, all rows are shown again.

Could anybody please help me with the code??

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to add a new column with

```
=ArrayFormula(if(isblank(A2:A);;if((A2:A="Value1")+(A2:A="Value2")>0;"ok";"nok")))
```

and the filter on this new column wether it is ok or nok

Comment: Yep, filters and filter views are much less complicated, thx!!